# 409 ETELGRAM Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running

Tags: node.js, bots, telegram, node-telegram-bot-api

i created a telegram bot in node js node-telegram-bot-api and deployed in free hosting **
[RENDER*](https://dashboard.render.com/)

- and this happened *error: [polling_error] {"code":"ETELEGRAM","message":"ETELEGRAM: 409 Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running"}*
  but in console of my computer i didnt see this problem

How can i fix this error

i tried chanching API token of my telegram bot
and changing [github repository](https://github.com/abdulloh5007/nodeJs-bot)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because you use the same bot token for dev and prod server. You should create in bot father different bots for dev and for the product server. If you use the same bot token in the product and dev server it might cause this problem

Comment: But i have written token and other API in environment variables The token which i wrote the same bot fathers token. So what should i do create an other bot then can you show how to create bots which i need

Answer (score 0):

you are probably running your bot on the server already, then you attempted to run it again in your local Server, whichever way you're trying to run similar bot on multiple server at the same time. you need to run it from only one place

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).